# Encode image sequence to video stream and send it through network

Tags: c#, video-processing, encoder

I can get plenty of images of desktop capture, but I want to encode them with some video encoder, then send the video data through network. The another application (Data receiver) will get that data and play them on the screen.

How can I encode images to video, and send them?

```cs
// There is a simple desktop capture class
public class DesktopCapture
{
    public readonly Bitmap Frame;
    public readonly Graphics FrameGraphics;
    private readonly Rectangle CaptureArea;

    public DesktopCapture(Rectangle captureArea)
    {
        CaptureArea = captureArea;
        Frame = new Bitmap(captureArea.Width, captureArea.Height);
        FrameGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(Frame);
    }
    
    public void Capture()
    {
        FrameGraphics.CopyFromScreen(CaptureArea.Location, Point.Empty, CaptureArea.Size);
    }
}
```

What I want:

```cs
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 5555));

DesktopCapture desktopCap = new DesktopCapture(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds);

NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();
VideoStreamWriter videoStream = new VideoStreamWriter(Encoder.SomeEncoder, clientStream);
videoStreamWriter.StartEncoding();
while (true)
{
    desktopCap.Capture();
    videoStreamWriter.EncodeFrame(desktopCap.Frame);
}
```

Comment: Video or stream? What Format?

Comment: What are your latency requirement? Most video compression algorithms compresses long sequences of frames in a single block for better efficiency. The simple option to avoid this is MJpeg. There are better options, but none I know of that is available as a permissibly licensed .net library.

Comment: I'm trying to write a simple desktop sharing program, and currently I'm taking a screenshot of my desktop directly and sending it directly to another client via TCP, but this has a huge bandwidth requirement

Comment: I don't know much about video encoding and streaming, I just want to compress data through video encoding to reduce bandwidth usage

Comment: Although I tried to judge the updated part of the frame and only send the updated part to the client, the process alone was very performance-intensive, and the CPU was still a bit too slow to loop so many pixels

Comment: Is the [built-in H.264 encoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/h-264-video-encoder) not an option for you?Also if you can transfer data between WebBrowser component and your main code, then consider using HTML5's WebCodecs API for encoding frames (pixel data) as H.264 frames. Later you can package H264 frames inside an MP4 but is not needed for just playback (if the copy of your app on the receiving side knows how to decode the sent H.264)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend H.264 for screen capture. Common encoders work best with motion videos (like TV scenes) and employ lossy compression, which can distort the captured image especially things like text and straight lines. A better approach is to use lossless compression, such as the [LEAD Screen Capture Encoder](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/multimedia/filters/lead-screen-capture-encoder-2-0.html). The encoder part of the [free evaluation of LEADTOOLS Multimedia](https://leadtools.com/downloads), which includes other components for screen capture and streaming. Disclosure: I work for LEAD.